# Advice on predicting continuous dependent variable

Tags: r, forecasting, predictive-models, feature-selection

My challenge: maximize $R^2$ on an out of sample data set. 
Constraints:

1. Continuous dependent variable with negative values
2. Over 150 variables with no information about them
3. Some of these independent variables are categorical
4. Over 50,000 observations

My strategy: run a random forest, LASSO and linear regression model. Then blend (haven't done this before) them together. Thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Maximizing out-of-sample $R^2$ may not be a good idea, because this way you neglect forecast bias.

Suppose your true realized values are $y_{t+1}$ through $y_{t+n}$. Suppose you have two sets of predictions,

1. $\hat{y}_{t+1}$ through $\hat{y}_{t+n}$ and
2. $\hat{y}_{t+1}+c$ through $\hat{y}_{t+1}+c$,

where $c$ is some constant. If you define $R^2$ as the squared correlation between the true realized $y$ and the forecasted $\tilde{y}$ (which stands for $\hat{y}$ or $\hat{y}+c$), the out-of-sample $R^2$ values will be the same for alternative 1. as they are for alternative 2. Does this satisfy your needs?

You could use other forecast accuracy measures instead. Perhaps the closer to what you are targetting with out of sample $R^2$ would be Theil's $U$ (although be aware that there are at least two different definitions of Theil's $U$ out there in the literature). Check out, for example, Diebold ["Forecasting in Economics, Business, Finance and Beyond"](http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/Teaching221/Forecasting.pdf) (p. 441; incidentally, the textbook has been updated today!).

Comment: Different needs. Maximizing R2 is an exogenous condition (I would normally look to other measures). In addition, it's not time series.

Comment: OK, I will not argue against an exogenous condition. But what do you want to imply by saying "it's not time series"? The critique of out-of-sample $R^2$ applies also for non-time series data.

Comment: Follow up to this @RichardHardy. Is including all variables going to maximize R2 for an out of sample data set, rather then just in-sample?

Comment: No, I think including irrelevant variables is likely to reduce the out-of-sample $R^2$ (I suppose there may be some irrelevant variables in the set of 150). I will not attempt to prove it, but I think it should be possible to simulate the behaviour of the out-of-sample $R^2$ using toy examples with just two or three variables.